# Payment gateway for android where user can pay through phone credit

Tags: android, payment-gateway

When i try to make in-app purchase for an app which has google's default as payment method it shows following options:
-Bill my T-Mobile US account
-Add card

But for the same app in India it only shows:
-Add card

My question: Is there any payment gateway which we can use to achieve this? So that user can pay through their phone credit for in-app billing? Rather than using credit card?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a link button to paypal account which can be used for the payment gateway because android doesn't support any gateway. But, I have done it with a simple link button hope it will help.